# No package cgdb available on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum

I was trying to install cgdb on a CentOS 7 VM and got the above message `No package cgdb available`. Searching Google returned 0 results for this issue, which seems unusual. Is there a way to fix this? Am I missing some repository info? All other packages installed fine.

Comment: That package is provided by the `epel` repo. Is it enabled on the system?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes that solved it, thank you. If you put that as answer I can checkmark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cgdb` is provided by the `epel` repo.

To add it:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

That also enables it. If for some reason it doesn't, install `yum-utils`

```
yum install yum-utils
```

And then enable the repo:

```
yum-config-manager --enable epel
```